# How to change functions return type based on the input arguments in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I am trying to type a function, which takes an optional `transformResult`. I have a problem typing the `useQuery` function correctly, so it:

- Returns `QResult` type if `transformResult` is not provided.
- Returns `TResult` (or return type of `transformResult` callback, but I am not sure if this is possible) if the callback is provided.

How can I achieve this? I don't mind using functions override if it can solve my problem easily, however conditional types are preferred.

Thanks a lot in advance!

```js
type QueryOptions<QResult, TResult> = {
    transformResult?: (queryResult: QResult) => TResult;
    // Other options that are not so important
    enableDebug?: boolean;
};

function useQuery<QResult, TResult = QResult>(
    query: string,
    options?: QueryOptions<QResult, TResult>,
) {
    const queryResult = doSomeServerStuff<QResult>(query);
    if (options?.transformResult != null) {
        return options.transformResult(queryResult);
    } else {
        return queryResult;
    }
}

function doSomeServerStuff<Q>(query: string): Q {
    /* Not so important just to make it compile */
    return {} as Q;
}

//typeOf 'number' <- Good
const result = useQuery<number>('q');

// Expecting 'boolean' type, but 'number | boolean' is actual
const transformedResult = useQuery<number, boolean>('q', {
    transformResult: (qResult) => qResult != null,
});
```

Link to [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=30&ssc=4&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAigrhATiA8mYBLA9gOwM4A8MAShHnADbAA0UAKqeVQHxQC8UA3gFACQwiAIb4AZlkQBbRpWAB%20AFxQAFAEcEyaVUUkyMgJTtWDXVQDcfAPQWoKYAAskUDIkQQKEAG7DgULOmz4fBA4ggBG7gAiEKFwAOYKUKFYWO7C5gC%205twicDgAxpi4UHB4EPBIIESaNPTV7LDVzEp8ahWKeAIYOLHUfH6F%20AnlyGgDhDpMNcaTzL0GPLx5uB1QrRomPhwAJlgAylgSELtIHki7wHAiIlUbTWsgeua8GCLK-QF4sgB0AsJ4YpI6gBCDg4SgUeZ8XiuC6IHC%20fzLH5CUTiKQbVTqEDVR58dJQNylLhQmFwOGrLHVJ7pbg07K5AoBKA7faHY6IU6Ic6Xa4wO5Y9qdbp6bTE3gWABUUAAki43J5vFAJRY%20KTyZx8YI8LAMtxuFZQJAUK8AORgiShJAmqAEAC0UAA4skttwlvgfK5JvUSmUsQRzZbEE0TSoTbj9dYAKIAD0gjO6UBNSRSEGE1sNEFoMR8ZrgFscAB9EslUjhrRhtYICnBBBRXcsfL9UZIIFs6hwfcNKgGkFmS6mcMHQ7QFk3-mjqopVDjDKtgaDwb10o8gA)

Comment: Why are conditional types preferred? When the return type of a function depends on the argument types, that _exactly_ what function overloads are designed to solve.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function overloads shine here. When the return type of a function changes depending on the type if its argument, function overloads are nearly always the easiest way to implement that.

To start off I'd organize the type like so:

```
interface QueryOptionsBase {
    // Other irrelevant options
    enableDebug?: boolean;
}

interface QueryOptionsWithoutTransform extends QueryOptionsBase {
    transformResult?: undefined;
};

interface QueryOptionsWithTransform<QResult, TResult> extends QueryOptionsBase {
    transformResult: (queryResult: QResult) => TResult;
};

type QueryOptions<QResult, TResult> = QueryOptionsWithoutTransform | QueryOptionsWithTransform<QResult, TResult>
```

`QueryOptionsBase` is the properties that all paths have.

`QueryOptionsWithoutTransform` is the simple branch that has no transform.

`QueryOptionsWithTransform` is the branch that has the transform

`QueryOptions` is the union of both branches.

Then you implement the overloads like so:

```
function useQuery<QResult>(query: string, options?: QueryOptionsWithoutTransform): QResult
function useQuery<QResult, TResult = QResult>(query: string, options: QueryOptionsWithTransform<QResult, TResult>): TResult

function useQuery<QResult, TResult = QResult>(
    query: string,
    options?: QueryOptions<QResult, TResult>,
) {
    const queryResult = doSomeServerStuff<QResult>(query);
    if (options?.transformResult != null) {
        return options.transformResult(queryResult);
    } else {
        return queryResult;
    }
}
```

---

Not this works as expected:

```
// 'boolean' type
const transformedResult = useQuery<number, boolean>('q', {
    transformResult: (qResult) => qResult != null,
});
```

But also this:

```
// '{ foo: string; }' type
const transformedResultInferred = useQuery('q', {
    transformResult: (qResult) => { foo: 'bar' }),
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIoFdoE8DyAHMYAexAGcAhOUlAbwCgBIAeieRzAAtplgooIANhABuccMiIFiZRhBBwARkIAiEBegDmAfgBcyBUSJCxAbjoBfOnVCRYiFBmz5CJUgHVgnIujAAVKGKkMERQALbIEAAekCAAJqRomFC4Uq6U1Mj0DGABZMFhAEoQpOgCYLrI6HEQMKAQsWbmZtbg0PBIiU6pZB6c-oH5oQA8qEUlZQA0yL5jpWAAfBHRcvGdyc7SFFS0jDkDIaGzZXoAFACOSVhHYHqjxXMAlMgAvIsz92WNzWBYeA6XG1cI2uU3e4wWLzWKRcPU8HG8flyQQOyAAPlDAbC+kjBsCPmBQdd5lY6DAqggYZVqI5knjwfNzpc9KQcqANFNJDDSBUadDNr14T5+nkDg9btdSeTKehqZc6XNCfjIXd6YzsMzWSB2RJuqRbgDdQLhciwvLJtMiWKLfirGSQBTpFSILyzQTreDlUSTowLurkCyoGyJoxOZseQaua7FfTg08sghXGBkL7ktdIbEiABlIihCCZ6DCaCZsDoGAwV0MlNYB5mBjAGDIE6h1xaAB0exFhSVAEJnsgQKUBHHGAx+CWoCAdVz2ziDtc1an8TXGOYIgIMllRxBx5Oq9da5ZLJL7ZSM9nc-moIWoMXS+XUJWmf7NRorahMowmAAqZAAST4ggiGISZfkwjBjugE6ZKuVBoI0VgsD8fw4A2ADkA6hAo0CocgQwALTIAA4oYsR0AmZBJvwHp9jKzpyhhWFQAyqFnKhy50CwyAAKKRH8DpasgqEGEYEBiDhSEQFM6hJuh6CYdw6LCcYIA4cACSICWcACGRibIB2Jq5rEaY0bK2BDAx0BSYYynMaxUxZPpgzXKcZzXE8rzJmmvb9oOwbmOxnE8XxhACUJ1miSpem-JJ+g+IJFlQGi+jhWJPDqRS6BaTpFF6bOYT1Ncv4gDA0D8LEkK0byJwsah9m7Hlhz4i5bkvIsJw0MgwREHoQlwFAOH+X5NZAA)

Comment: Thanks, Alex for the detailed explanation. I was unaware that function overriding serves specifically for such usecase. This solution works great for me!